# ASP.NET Crystal Reports is not working in opera browser?

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, opera

ASP.NET Crystal Reports is working in IE, Firefox browsers well. But ASP.NET Crystal Reports is not working in opera browser. Please help.

Comment: [How to ask a question the smart way](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)

Comment: a little information would be helpful. I was going to write "a little more information"...

Answer (score 1):

My first guess is that Crystal Reports uses browser detection.
Have you tried masking/spoofing as a different browser? To do this press [F12] when you see the problem, then select "Edit site preferences", go to "Network" tab and change the "Browser identification" setting.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript will help you for navigation....

Firts time heard this problem , but i face same problem for different control...so it might help you...